# Define a function

Tags: math-mode

> Is it correct to define a function as follows?

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
 \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
  \usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{align*}
    \psi\colon&\mathbf{G}(p+q,d)\longrightarrow\mathbf{G}(q,d)\times \mathbf{G}(p,d)\\
    &\phantom{+++++}g\mapsto\left(\psi_1(g),\psi_2(g)\right),
     \end{align*}
    with $\psi_1(g)(j)=g(j)$ for all $1\leq j\leq q$ and $\psi_2(g) (j)=g(j+q)$ 
    for all $1\leq j\leq p$.
      \end{document}
```

I obtain

[image]

Comment: If you ask about mathematical correctness please do so on our sister site https://math.stackexchange.com/. If you want to know if that is the correct LaTeX code for *writing* such a definition then your question is correctly placed here. Please clarify.

Comment: @MartinScharrer No it is about define a function in Latex.

Comment: "define a function in LaTeX" is not a very good choice in wording, as LaTeX allows to define macros and also has definition for mathematically functions like sinus  etc.
 (`\sin`, `\cos`, etc.). You seem to mean "How to write a mathematically function definition in LaTeX", right?

Comment: @MartinScharrer Yes you are write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the alignment point at the arrow and use `\longmapsto`.

However, I find much better to use `\rightarrow` and `\mapsto`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\psi\colon \mathbf{G}(p+q,d) & \longrightarrow\mathbf{G}(q,d)\times \mathbf{G}(p,d)\\
g&\longmapsto (\psi_1(g),\psi_2(g)),
\end{align*}
with $\psi_1(g)(j)=g(j)$ for all $1\leq j\leq q$ and $\psi_2(g) (j)=g(j+q)$
for all $1\leq j\leq p$.

\begin{align*}
\psi\colon \mathbf{G}(p+q,d) & \rightarrow\mathbf{G}(q,d)\times \mathbf{G}(p,d)\\
g&\mapsto (\psi_1(g),\psi_2(g)),
\end{align*}
with $\psi_1(g)(j)=g(j)$ for all $1\leq j\leq q$ and $\psi_2(g) (j)=g(j+q)$
for all $1\leq j\leq p$.

\end{document}
```

[image]